# implicitWait for WiniumDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, winium

Is there any way to set wait for winium driver other than `thread.sleep()`. I tried implicit wait but getting this exception:

> "'setTimeout' is not valid or implemented command"

Below is the code snippet:

```
options = new DesktopOptions();
options.setApplication(String);
driver = new winiumDriver(new URL("..."),options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting using the code you're using?

Have you tried: ```driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));```

Comment: Below is the error which i am getting: 
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: 'setTimeout' is not valid or implemented command